# Is it possible to power target microcontroller from AVRISP mkII using Atmel Studio

Tags: avr, atmel-studio

I'm using the Atmel Studio IDE and a AVRISP mkII to program microcontrollers. I've always powered the microcontrollers to be programmed with an external power supply but I was wondering if it is possible to power the target microcontroller through the AVRISP mkII itself?

Answer (score 2):

It is with a bit of a mod, see EEVBlog #158:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ICQXqVy3Hpc

Comment: I was hoping that there was an integrated function to power the target microcontroller by cheching a box or something in the Atmel Studio IDE.. Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Can you summarize the mod, in the event that this link breaks/expires?

Answer (score 2):

I've found very nice step by step instruction at the [Arduino forum](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=125502.0) with the following pics:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hope it will help someone...

Answer (score 1):

I found a reference a long time ago to modify my AVRISP.  Basically I added a mini toggle switch on the front cover of the AVRISP and it connects the +5 from the USB connector to the VCC pin on the ISP cable.  There isn't a nice jumper or set of solder pads for doing this.

My connections are from the outside pin on the green LED (away from the USB connector) to what looks like pin 5 of the ISP connector on the bottom of the board.  Pictures of this mod are pretty common as this isn't an uncommon thing to want to do.

The switch is pretty important.  I would NOT plug or unplug the ISP cable from the device being programmed with the power on.  I also would NOT recommend connecting USB power to a device with its own separate power source.